# How to copy png file with text editor?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, png

How do I copy a png file with text editor on Windows? When I open a file with text editor and copy and paste the contents into a new file, the new file is corrupted and unopenable. How is this file any different from the original? How do I fix this?

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WTnx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is sample. In image file (which is binary file, not text) you have symbols from 0 to 255 (per byte). And symbols from 0 to 32 (decimal) are not printable. Text editor can interpret from them only space, tab and newline. The rest are usually ignored. So when you copy the information you copy only part of it and because of this you can't create new file to be like the original. Even save operation from text editor may destroy the image structure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that text can be stored in several completely different ways which only *look* the same in a text editor. Converting from one such format to another is harmless for actual text, but would completely mangle non-text data. (PNG files are not text – they aren't read as a series of lines.)

For example, a text file might use either a two-byte CR+LF line separator or a one-byte LF (or even a CR if it came from old MacOS). If you open a non-text file in a text editor, it'll try to interpret every CR+LF *and* every lone LF as line separators – you can't tell which lines used which just by looking at the Notepad window. Saving the "text" into a new file will end up replacing all LFs with CR+LF, so now many binary values are different (10 became 13) and shifted in their position (because an extra byte was inserted).

(The PNG format even has a feature specifically to detect this kind of corruption.)

As another example, the same text might be stored in UTF-8 encoding (with or without a BOM marker) or in UTF-16 encoding (which has two subtypes + again with/without BOM) or in various ISO8859 encodings. If you load the PNG file as if it was ISO8859-1 text and then save it as UTF-8 text, it'll look the same in a text editor but the actual byte values that are saved will be completely different.

For a third example, binary files often contain the NUL (0x00) byte in various places, which completely disappears in some text editors. They also often contain bytes in the "control" range (0x01 to 0x1F), *some* of which are commonly found in text (tab, line break) but some aren't used in text files at all (e.g. BEL) and a text editor might decide to discard them.